# Cloudflare 524 w/ nodejs + express

Tags: node.js, azure, express, tcp, cloudflare

I'm running a nodejs webserver on azure using the express library for http handling. We've been attempting to enable cloudflare protection on the domains pointing to this box, but when we turn cloudflare proxying on, we see cycling periods of requests succeeding, and requests failing with a 524 error. I understand this error is returned when the server fails to respond to the connection with an HTTP response in time, but I'm having a hard time figuring out why it is

A. Only failing sometimes as opposed to all the time

B. Immediately fixed when we turn cloudflare proxying off.

I've been attempting to confirm the TCP connection using 
tcpdump -i  eth0 port 443 | grep cloudflare (the request come over https) and have seen curl requests fail seemingly without any traffic hitting the box, while others do arrive. For further reference, these requests should be and are quite quick when they succeed, so I'm having a hard time believe the issue is due to a long running process stalling the response.

I do not believe we have any sort of IP based throttling or firewall (at least not intentionally?)
Any ideas greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was caused by DNS resolution.

On Azure, you can configure a custom domain name for your created webapp. And according to the CloudFlare usage, you need to switch the DNS resolution to CloudFlare DNS server, please see more infomation for configuring domain name https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/.

You can try to refer to the faq doc of CloudFlare [How do I enter Windows Azure DNS records in CloudFlare?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168976-How-do-I-enter-Windows-Azure-DNS-records-in-CloudFlare-) to make sure the DNS settings is correct.

Comment: I guess I should have included that the original DNS is coming from DNSEasy, not azure, sorry. The webapp is our own deployment on an Azure classic VM

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cookies.

Had a similar issue when I changed cloudflare settings to a new host but cloudflare cookies for the domain was doing something funky to the request (I am guessing it might be trying to contact the old host?)